# Configure a db2 datasource with Thorntail / Wildfly Swarm

Tags: db2, wildfly-swarm, thorntail

Has anyone managed to configure a db2 datasource with Thorntail / Wildfly Swarm?

As far as I understand: As soon as I pull in the datasources fraction, the db2 driver should be autodetected according to documentation (https://docs.thorntail.io/2.3.0.Final/#auto-detecting-jdbc-drivers_thorntail).
So the only thing I should have to do is reference "ibmdb2" as the driver-name in my datasource, right?

**pom.xml** (using Thorntail 2.3.0.Final)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
        <artifactId>datasources</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
        <version>10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.22.29</version>
    </dependency>
```

**project-defauls.yml**

```
swarm:
  context:
    path: /

  datasources:
    data-sources:
      MYDS:
        driver-name: ibmdb2
        connection-url: jdbc:db2://host:port/schema
        user-name: user
        password: password
```

Currently I get the following error on startup:

```
2019-05-02 09:07:52,747 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.datasources] (main) THORN1003: Auto-detected JDBC driver for ibmdb2
2019-05-02 09:07:57,660 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 16) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "ibmdb2")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0114: Failed to load datasource class: com.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2XADataSource"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found a bug in the JDBC driver autodetection code. The driver was (probably) autodetected, but it was wrongly configured. Specifically, [this line of code](https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail/blob/master/fractions/javaee/datasources/src/main/java/org/wildfly/swarm/datasources/runtime/drivers/DB2DriverInfo.java#L49) sets the XA datasource class name to `com.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2XADataSource`, which doesn't exist. (That's actually what your error message says, but I also confirmed it by looking into the JDBC driver JAR.) The correct class name is `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource`. I filed [THORN-2398](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN-2398) and submitted a PR with a fix.

I'm not sure if there's a simple workaround, because JDBC driver autodetection is performed after all configuration is applied. Perhaps the following hack might work. Define a new JDBC driver in `project-defaults.yml` like this:

```
thorntail:
  datasources:
    jdbc-drivers:
      mydb2:
        driver-module-name: com.ibm.db2jcc
        driver-xa-datasource-class-name: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource
```

But keep everything else intact. That means there will be 2 JDBC drivers for DB2, one autodetected (which will create the `com.ibm.db2jcc` module), and the second one you create that will piggyback on the infrastructure created by the first. If that works, just change `driver-name: ibmdb2` in your data source to `driver-name: mydb2`.

If this doesn't work, you'll have to move off of JDBC driver autodetection for now, until the issue is fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I created my own jdbc-driver definition. This works perfectly. However I still get the error from the auto-detection. Is there a way to disable JDBC driver autodetection?

Comment: I don't think turning JDBC driver autodetection off is possible. If you have a JDBC driver among your dependencies, it will be autodetected. You can remove it from your Maven POM, but then you will have to create your own `module.xml` for it etc. There is _some_ documentation for it at https://docs.thorntail.io/2.4.0.Final/#configuring-the-jdbc-driver-manually_thorntail